# How to determine whether a given point lies inside or outside of a triangle in 3D?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, decision-problems

For example if i have triangle defined by following points 
[A=(15.0, 14, 15.0), B=(15.0, -45, 15.0), C=(-15.0, 14, 15.0)], and consider the point need to be project p=(15,78,0). I want to determine, whether the points lies inside or not

I found some of answers related to my question, but i could not get the proper idea behind those answers. There are methodology and algorithm available for 2D. In the case of 3D, how to determine? I need some example in order to develop code(currently i am using python) Can someone help me to figure it out?

Comment: If it is inside the triangle, then it is a convex combination of the vertices. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Have you searched for a 'point in polygon' problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "lies inside"? Note that $A,B,C$ all have $z=15$, but $P$ has $z=0$, so it's not even in the same plane. Or are you talking about the orthogonally projected point $(15,78,15)$? Then here it's really a 2D problem as you can get rid of $z$. Is this part of a more general problem where $A,B,C$ may lie in an arbitrary plane?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for replying! First of all, I would like to check whether a given point lies inside a triangle or not. I made a mistake in previous post.            
For example Consider following co-ordinates of three nodes   [(-15.0, 36.25, 137.10000610351562), (15.0, 36.25, 0.0), (-15.0, 36.25, 0.0)]  and point is      [ -15, 13.75 ,137.1000061]. As i have mentioned in previous post, i have found methodology and algorithm for 2D . Since it is 3D , I need to know to method to determine  it.

Comment: Check that the points are coplanar, then project to one of the coordinate planes and use your 2-D algorithm.

Comment: Thank you guyzz!!